# Create an mp3 file from scratch C#

Tags: c#, audio, mp3

As part of some experimentation, I thought of something, how can I create a .mp3 file from scratch in C#, that actually sounds like something, e.g, create an mp3 file that plays the note: C#, or B flat?

How can I achieve this, and it must be an mp3 file, not a wav, or anything else.

Comment: @mekici why not? It's just a file format, and a note is just a frequency.

Comment: Have a look at this, it might get you started http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MP3Compressor.aspx

Comment: @mekici Why you say it's not possible ? There are audio programs that simulate pianos and other instruments (they include the different notes) which are sounds that you can record then convert to MP3 format or whatever.

Comment: @mekici, my response is simply, you're wrong.  *Of course it's possible*.  MP3s were created using software.  C# makes software.

Comment: I think the bottom line though is that it's a *lot* of work to get something if you're wanting to do it from scratch (ie generating samples and then manually encoding them in the MP3 file format).  If you're using wavetable/synth libraries to generate instrument samples and libraries or converters to output to MP3 then this becomes easier.  If you do it yourself you'll end up with a pure sine wave which is probably not what you want.  If you want a usable result, use high level libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I'm not going to be able to give you exact code, but I can give a starting point.

So basically the steps would be

1. Find the frequency of the wave you want. Look at [this](http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html). C# (nice choice by the way!) is 17.32HZ
2. Convert the frequency to [LPCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_pulse_code_modulation), which is just a series of amplitude values.
3. Convert the LPCM encoded array to an MP3 file. This is probably the hardest, but LPCM forms that basis of the [WAV format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) and there are converters to convert that to MP3. Have a look at the NAudio baalazamon found. It supports PCM.

Answer (score 1):

I would try using [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) it's quite powerful. The main purpose was to manipulate audio files but it's worth to try.